# I am struggling to do a pull down to refresh the page - appium for iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

We have an app that if you pull down it will refresh the page, similar to that of Facebook ir Instagram.

Currently I am working with Appium Webdriver on Iphone 14 Pro Max.

I have the following code

```
while(!await pendingRequest.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 180000})) {
        await driver.touchPerform([
            { action: 'press', options: { x: 100, y: 100 }},
            { action: 'wait', options: { ms: 1000 }},
            { action: 'moveTo', options: { x: 100, y: 650 }},
            { action: 'release' },
            { action: 'wait', options: { ms: 2000 }}
        ]);
    }
```

While we wait for pendingRequest to appear, I want to do periodic pulldowns to refresh every 2 seconds. I have tried various combinations of sizes using appSize.length and appSize.height to no avail.